# Adding image to Dialog Element

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to create my entire app's UI using Droid.Dialog in MvvmCross. More specifically setting the background image and then adding a header image to the view, as well as input fields and buttons.

I am stuck trying to get a header image into the view. Firstly here is a wireframe explaining what I mean by header image:

[image: wireframe]

I have managed to set the background gradient image using:

```
 using (var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Backgroud))
            Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

I have then tried to add the header image using the `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid` stuff like this:

```
var img = new ImageView(this.BaseContext);
img.LayoutParameters = new Gallery.LayoutParams(330, 110);
img.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Header);
Root = new RootElement()
{
    new Section(){new ImageElement(img)}
};
```

However, the image appears as a tiny blotch in the UI.

Doing this in `AXML` I would set the image as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Header" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm basically stuck trying to figure out how to get the image into the view at the top of the screen and with the right dimensions!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or am I better off creating the views using the native AXML and IB respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look what is inside the `ImageElement` and what happens when you call the ctor with the `ImageView` argument, then you will discover that the image is scaled to 48x44.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog/Elements/ImageElement.cs#L52:

```
private const int dimx = 48;
private const int dimy = 44;

...

private ImageView Scale(ImageView source)
{
    var drawable = (BitmapDrawable) source.Drawable;
    var bitmap = drawable.Bitmap;
    var bMapScaled = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, dimx, dimy, true);
    source.SetImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
    return source;
}
```

So you have a couple of options:

1. Create your own Element, where you are in the control of what is done with the `ImageView`
2. Do it by creating a native Android Layout instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I'll try going with option 1 and see how I get on, any idea why it was built to be a static size?

Comment: No idea at all why that was.

Comment: Just wondering if a pull request with a clean up would be a good idea or as you say just create my own element? It's not expected functionality (IMO) so hence my question.

Comment: Do whatever makes you happy. Pull requests are appreciated, but if you are in a hurry and need just to get things working, then do whatever is fastest.